# Assertion failure when assigning null to QObject* property of C++ type in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

When I uncomment the line below, I get an assertion:

> ASSERT: "!from.isNull() && !to.isNull()" in file [...]\qtdeclarative\src\qml\qml\qqmlpropertycache.cpp, line 1586

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QtQuick>

class Inventory : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Inventory() {
    }
};

class InventoryModel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Inventory *inventory READ inventory WRITE setInventory NOTIFY inventoryChanged)
public:
    InventoryModel() : mInventory(0) {
    }

    Inventory *inventory() const {
        return mInventory;
    }

    void setInventory(Inventory *inventory) {
        if (inventory != mInventory) {
            mInventory = inventory;
            emit inventoryChanged();
        }
    }
signals:
    void inventoryChanged();
private:
    Inventory *mInventory;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

//    qRegisterMetaType<Inventory*>();
    qmlRegisterType<InventoryModel>("Qml", 1, 0, "InventoryModel");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

import Qml 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    InventoryModel {
        inventory: null
    }
}
```

I'm building with Qt 5.4 (qtdeclarative is at f9ee33f9683a4cd4d1a2e41efa6e8d124e9d731d). Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Qt 5.4 have not been released yet, as of Sep 6, 2014. Do I understand correctly that  you are using some git snapshot? Does your code works with 5.3.1?

Comment: Yeah, I'm building from source. I tried with 5.3 and it's the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like the problem is `inventory: window.inventory` in QML. The assertion is triggered because `window.inventory` is null.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's `null`, though.

Comment: I've updated the example to make it simpler. The problem occurs when registering `Inventory*` as a metatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try qmlRegisterType instead:

```
qmlRegisterType<Inventory>("Qml", 1, 0, "Inventory");
```

The assertion could be related to this [bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-39614?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel)

Comment: That's not true. I've been registering type pointers with no problems, and Qt code does it as well: `git grep "qRegisterMetaType<.*\*>"` in qtbase.git, for example.

Comment: Thanks. :) Strange that a Google search didn't show that bug - a good reminder to search the bug reports first. I now get what appears to be double deletion issues upon exiting with this approach, but this is most likely an issue in my code.

Comment: Well, I googled "[qml pointer qRegisterMetaType](https://www.google.com.my/search?q=qml+pointer+qRegisterMetaType)".